# Python 2.7 find IP address and replace with text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have used Python to extract a route table from a router and am trying to

1. strip out superfluous text, and
2. replace the destination of each route with a text string to match a different customer grouping.

At the moment I have::

```
infile = "routes.txt"
outfile = "output.txt"

delete_text = ["ROUTER1# sh run | i route", "ip route"]

client_list = ["CUST_A","CUST_B"]
subnet_list = ["1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8"]

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_text:
       line = line.replace(word, "")
    for word in subnet_list:
       line = line.replace("1.2.3.4", "CUST_A")
    for word in subnet_list:
       line = line.replace("5.6.7.8", "CUST_B")
    fout.write(line)


fin.close()
fout.close()

f = open('output.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

This works to an extent but when it searches and replaces for e.g. `5.6.7.8` it also picks up that string within other IP addresses e.g. `5.6.7.88`, and replaces them also which I don't want to happen.

What I am after is an exact match only to be found and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with explicit word boundaries (`\b`):

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b5.6.7.8\b', 'CUST_B', 'test 5.6.7.8 test 5.6.7.88 test')
'test CUST_B test 5.6.7.88 test'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found out your approach is bad because it results in false positives (i.e., undesirable matches). You should parse the lines into tokens then match the individual tokens. That might be as simple as first doing `tokens = line.split()` to split on whitespace. That, however, may not work if the line contains quoted strings. Consider what the result of this statement: `"ab 'cd ef' gh".split()`. So you might need a more sophisticated parser.

You could use the `re` module to perform substitutions using the `\b` meta sequence to ensure the matches begin and end on a "word" boundary. But that has its own, unique, failure modes. For example, consider that the `.` (period) character matches any character. So doing `re.sub('\b5.6.7.8\b', ...)` as @NPE suggested will actually match not just the literal word `5.6.7.8` but also `5x6.7y8`. That may not be a concern given the inputs you expect but is something most people don't consider and is therefore another source of bugs. Regular expressions are seldom the correct tool for a problem like this one.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, I've been testing with this and the re.sub function just seems to print out the below string in a loop : CUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTBCUSTB .
I have amended the code snippet above to : 
for word in subnet_list:
       line = re.sub(r'\b5.6.7.8\b',  'CUST_B', '5.6.7.88')

Ideally I would like the string element to be replaced in all of the list occurrences along with preserving the list structure ?